# Every polynomial with real coefficients is the sum of cubes of three polynomials

Tags: polynomials

How to prove that every polynomial with real coefficients is the sum of three polynomials raised to the 3rd degree? Formally the statement is:

> $\forall f\in\mathbb{R}[x]\quad \exists g,h,p\in\mathbb{R}[x]\quad f=g^3+h^3+p^3$

Comment: I'm confused by this question. Surely a linear function or a quadratic for $f$ is a simple counter example.

Comment: @IanMiller No. $3x^2+3x=(x+1)^3+(-x)^3+(-1)^3.$

Comment: Oh right. My bad.

Comment: What is this, a contest question or something?

Comment: @JackM, yes, it was offered on a contest

Comment: @Glinka what contest?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

We have that the following identity holds
$$(x+1)^3+2(-x)^3+(x-1)^3=6x.$$
Hence
$$\left(\frac{f(x)+1}{6^{1/3}}\right)^{3}+\left(\frac{-f(x)}{3^{1/3}}\right)^{3}+
\left(\frac{f(x)-1}{6^{1/3}}\right)^{3}=f(x).$$

Comment: Great answer. This appears to be extendable to all powers as:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(x-\frac{n-1}{2}+i\right)^n\cdot(-1)^i\cdot{n-1\choose i}=n!\cdot x$$

Comment: @IanMiller For $n = 2$ you get $-2x$ on the left. I think the right side should be $(-1)^{n-1} n! \cdot x$

Comment: @Jay Thanks. I did drop that bit somehow from my expression.

Comment: Over the rationals: I wonder for what $f\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ there exist $g,h,p\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $f=g^3+h^3+p^3$ (since the cube root of six is clearly irrational).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen : [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53109/something-new-in-old-question-about-sums-of-three-polynomial-cubes) could be related.

Comment: @Watson Good find, thanks.

Comment: Does this include for cubed perfect numbers as well? How every perfect number cubed can be written as the sum of three cubes? I believe this has been conjectured